# Is it possible to process xml under chakracore?

Tags: javascript, xml, chakracore

I am exchanging xml data between various platforms and would like to use ChakraCore as a headless JS scripting environment. Being headless there would be no DOM.

So would it be possible to use JSdom and jQuery in that situation?

Edit: To clarify I want to use ChakraCore under .net so there is only one executable to run, JS can be used for scripting and it's a simple installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to embed ChakraCore, you could just use node-chakracore and leverage quite a few of the existing node npm packages for network connectivity, XML/JSON parsing, etc. If an external node-chakracore program won't work, you could use a webpack configuration to target ChakraCore as a non-browser environment and it will stub a lot of the missing browser-based functions.

Comment: I wonder if I might not be better off running node as a sub-process under .net